# Are credit cards accepted in Strasbourg Christmas markets?

Tags: france, money, christmas

We are thinking to visit "The Capital of Christmas" (Strasbourg, France) and it's famous Christmas markets on the beautifully illuminated streets with delicious aromas and holiday atmosphere.

Will we be able to pay with a credit card when shopping in the Strasbourg Christmas markets, or EUR cash is our only reliable option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no information one way or the other on the Strasbourg [Christmas Market](https://noel.strasbourg.eu/en/conseils-pour-marche-de-noel-en-toute-tranquilite) site.

Conventional Wisdom would suggest that you should be prepared to pay cash; but I would not be surprised that (most) vendors accept cards.

Worse case scenario will be to hunt an ATM.

Comment: Strasbourg is (currently) in France, which means you are probably correct.  Just a few miles away the other side of the Rhine in Germany, the answer would be a very definite "Hell no!"